# How to Apply OCR and Extract Text for the Image In Korean Language

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, easyocr

I need to implement an accurate text detection algorithm for extracting text from an image. Currently, I am using EasyOCR, but the results are not satisfactory. For instance, when processing the image, the expected output is

```
부동산 매매 계약서
```

but the code produces

```
부 동 산 떼 더 겨 약 서
```

Therefore, I need to explore alternative methods to improve the accuracy of text recognition.

Is it possible to increase the resolution and apply EasyOCR? Can anyone solve this problem?

```
!pip install easyocr
import cv2
import easyocr
import numpy as np
def extract_text_from_image(image):
    # Read the image
    #image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply adaptive thresholding to create a binary image
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Find contours in the binary image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Find the contour with the maximum area (foreground)
    max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Create a mask for the foreground contour
    mask = np.zeros_like(binary)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], 0, 255, -1)

    # Apply the mask to the original image
    preprocessed_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    # Initialize the EasyOCR reader
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en','ko'])

    # Convert the preprocessed image to grayscale
    preprocessed_gray = cv2.cvtColor(preprocessed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Perform OCR on the preprocessed image
    results = reader.readtext(preprocessed_gray)

    # Concatenate the extracted text into a single line
    extracted_text = ''
    for result in results:
        extracted_text += result[1] + ' '

    return extracted_text.strip()



img = cv2.imread(file_path)
text = extract_text_from_image(img)
```

[image: Input Image]

Comment: since you already tagged opencv: opencv contains some text *detection* algorithms. I don't know how they compare to what actual OCR libraries give you.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can you provide the code for that. How it works?